# What are the requirements for national parks?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm trying to place a national park here:

[image: Where I want to place the park]

But the button to create one with the `Naturalist` is greyed out:

[image: The button is disabled]

I know the civopedia lists the requirements for building a national park, but they are either wrong or I'm having a hard time understanding them:

- **The tiles must be natural wonders, Mountains or a tile with an Appeal of Charming or better.** As you can see the top are both `Breathtaking` and the bottom ones are part of the `Great Barrier Reef` wonder
- **All four tiles must be owned by the same city.** All tiles are within the boarders of Mbwila
- **The tiles for a diamond shape.** All tiles are connected close to each other in a diamond shape
- **No tile can have an improvement or district on it.** All tiles are in their initial condition.

So I'm probably missing something. Can someone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing because I don't understand the rules entirely myself, but I think this is not a diamond shape and that is the reason it doesn't work. If there is a possible placement, it is highlighted with white borders.

Comment: @MadScientist could you explain to me what makes this not diamond shaped and how a diamond shape would look like in the game? The white borders similar when you move great artist? I can't see any of them in my empire.

Comment: I only had one national park so far, and the diamond shape was vertical, yours is diagonal, and I have no idea if those count. If your naturalist is selected, you should see the white border around any valid tiles, and it looks like the borders visible for all the great persons.

Comment: @Ellesedil I will try, but this could take a lot of time since this title is 4 tiles away from the city. Those can't be bought and take a lot of turns to acquire

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is for sure that **your diamond shape is diagonal instead of vertical**. (Note that the Spring 2017 update, or an update prior to that, fixed the Civilopedia entry to specify that the diamond must be vertical.)

[image: picture of Civilopedia entry]

For this to be a legal configuration for a national park, it would have to include your Niter mine, the two land squares you want, and the rightmost of the water tiles you want to use. However, this is also conditional on your tiles being appealing enough since they are not natural wonders or mountains:

[image: Correct placement of the national park]

You're probably SOL unless you want to scrap your Niter mine and possibly plant a forest instead (I'm not sure if new-growth forest can be a national park or it's only old-growth (never cleared or planted)).

Frankly I think national parks are either underpowered or too hard to establish.

Comment: You're correct. The national park has to be in a vertical shape (for god-knows-what reason). Removing the Niter also allowed me to create the park: [image](http://i.imgur.com/IIjIjLW.png)

Comment: It's bizarre that they don't specify this, or show some kind of diagram. +1 For figuring it out.

Comment: I can confirm that planting new trees in a national park is possible.

Comment: Wow, that is a ridiculously limiting requirement. I hope they change that in a future patch.

Comment: Yea this needs to be fixed, took me two hours and three potential national park placements to find this and figure out why my angled diamond wouldn't create.

Comment: I can confirm that already planted second growth forests are valid (_sufficient appeal provided, of course_).

Answer (score -4):

Step 1: find 4 tiles that fit the rules of a national park tile that are adjecent to each other

Step 2: use your unit on one of those tiles, preferably closest to the tile or on the tile you want in the park the most

Tip: planting forests increase the Appeal level of the tiles in the park