# What is a "valid National Park tile"

Tags: civilization-6

I've just build a naturalist in my game, and I want to use it's ability to build a national park, but wherever I place it the button doesn't seem to light up.

What determines if a tile is valid as a national park?

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/290165/what-are-the-requirements-for-national-parks